# gestureRecognizers - new region

Tags: ios5

I've changed the region of the screen in which the user can navigate using gestures by creating an arbitrary view (called gestureRegion) and assigning gestureRecognizers to it.

But this only overides the tap gesture.The swipe right and left gestures seems to still work on the entire page. Is there a way to overide the swipe gestures? Or disable it entirely?

My code:

self.gestureRegion.gestureRecognizers = self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers;
[self.pageViewController.view addSubview:gestureRegion];

Apple Doc:

gestureRecognizers
An array of UIGestureRecognizer objects that are configured to handle user interaction. (read-only)
@property(nonatomic, readonly) NSArray *gestureRecognizers
Discussion
These gesture recognizers are initially attached to a view in the page view controller’s hierarchy. To change the region of the screen in which the user can navigate using gestures, they can be placed on another view.
Availability
Available in iOS 5.0 and later.
Declared In
UIPageViewController.h

Answer (score 1):

It appears that to get rid of the swipe but not the tap you can remove the Pan gesture recognizer from the view...  I put this in the viewDidLoad of the RootViewController class in the Xcode auto generated page view app.

```
for (UIGestureRecognizer *gR in self.pageViewController.gestureRecognizers) {
    if ([gR isKindOfClass:[UIPanGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        [[gR view] removeGestureRecognizer:gR];
    }
}
```